# my calculations for solving veloicty are not working please review my code

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose a ball is thrown straight up in the air with an initial velocity of 50 
feet per second and an initial height of 5 feet. How high will the ball be after 3 seconds
Here is what I have so far:

```
h = input(" Enter the initial height of the ball:")
v = input(" Enter the initial velocity of the ball:")
t = input("Enter the time of the ball")
maxH = maxHeight(h,v)
ballT = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))

print("The maximum height of the ball is", maxH, "feet.")
print("The ball will hit the ground after approximately", ballT, "seconds.")
ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))
maxH = (h + (v*h) - (16*t*t))
```

Ive been working on this code for a while I am stuck on the calculations, also I thought using input and print  function returning as string data was acceptable. I am new to coding so any explanations I would appreciate in great details, thanks!

Updated code

```
h = input (" Enter the initial height of the ball:"),int(h)
v = input (" Enter the initial velocity of the ball:"),int (v)
t = input("Enter the time of the ball"), int(t)


maxH =(h,v )
maxH = h + (-(v ** 2 )) / ( 2 * (-16))

ballH = (h + (v*t) - (6 * t * t))
ballT = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))


print("The maximum height of the ball is", maxH, "feet.")
print("The ball will hit the ground after approximately", ballT, "seconds.")
ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))
```

Comment: If this is python, then you should be getting a particular error message that should be telling you something... did you not read it? Hint: What is `h`?

Comment: H will be a number, so I'm missing the conversion for it to be a number?

Comment: Yes. And now that you've figured that out, what must you do to convert it?

Comment: Can I put it as, h=input int(h)("enter the initial height...")?

Comment: No... You can't ...

Comment: `h = input(....); h = int(h)`

Comment: Okay I thought doing that might redefine h so the original h= wouldn't work right, is that only if it's put on a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When receiving an input to be used as an int, the input needs to be cast from its input type (string) to an int.

   ```
   num = int (input("Enter an int"))
   ```
2. You are attempting to set maxH according to some function maxHeight(). Unless you have defined maxHeight elsewhere, you need to define the function and include in it the equation you are using to determine the max height.

   ```
   def maxHeight(height, velocity):
       # calculate max height here
   ```
3. On the topic of your maxHeight calculation, you are using this formula:

   > maxH = (h + (v * h) - (16 * t * t))

   This formula doesn't calculate the max height; rather, it calculates the height after a given time. In order to calculate the max height, you should use this formula:

   ```
   maxH = h + (-(v ** 2)) / (2 * (-16))
   ```

   Which comes from the equation: v2 ^ 2 = v1 ^ 2 + 2a * s (where 's' is distance)
4. The equation in 3. can be plugged into the function in 2. in order for your original function call:

   > maxH = maxHeight(h, v)

   To properly provide the max height to maxH (remember to set the return value of the function).
5. You can follow a similar process to determine the ballHeight after a specific time if you set up a similar function and use the equation that you posted:

   > ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))

   Within a function ballTime(), referenced in a similar fashion:

   ```
   ballT = ballTime(h, v, t)
   ```

## Fixing Updated Code

### Current Code

```
h = input (" Enter the initial height of the ball:"),int(h)
v = input (" Enter the initial velocity of the ball:"),int (v)
t = input("Enter the time of the ball"), int(t)


maxH =(h,v )
maxH = h + (-(v ** 2 )) / ( 2 * (-16))

ballH = (h + (v*t) - (6 * t * t))
ballT = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))


print("The maximum height of the ball is", maxH, "feet.")
print("The ball will hit the ground after approximately", ballT, "seconds.")
ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))
```

### Fixed Code

```
h = input ("Enter the initial height of the ball:"); h = int(h)
v = input ("Enter the initial velocity of the ball:"); v = int (v)
t = input ("Enter the time of the ball"); t = int(t)

maxH = h + (-(v ** 2 )) / ( 2 * (-16))

ballT = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))

print("The maximum height of the ball is", maxH, "feet.")
print("After",t,"seconds the ball will be at a height of",ballT,"feet.")
```

I rephrased the final print statement to what you described your goal as in the original question. If you really want to know how long it will be until the ball hits the ground (after the input time), let me know.

Comment: h = input (" Enter the initial height of the ball:"),int(h)
v = input (" Enter the initial velocity of the ball:"),int (v)
t = input("Enter the time of the ball"), int(t)


maxH =(h,v )
maxH = h + (-(v ** 2 )) / ( 2 * (-16))

ballH = (h + (v*t) - (6 * t * t))
ballT = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))


print("The maximum height of the ball is", maxH, "feet.")
print("The ball will hit the ground after approximately", ballT, "seconds.")
ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))

Comment: Thank you, I think something is wrong with how I converted my h,v, and t to numbers..

Comment: What were you trying to say with that comment (your first comment*)? It appears to be updated code, so you should add that to the question post, since the formatting makes it much harder to read as a comment.

Comment: I added the full module to my answer.

Your code is most of the way to completion, you just skipped making the functions and calculated the heights inline, which is fine. There three lines you can remove from your updated code: "maxH = h + (-(v ** 2 )) / ( 2 * (-16))" , "ballH = (h + (v*t) - (6 * t * t))" , and "ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))".

Comment: Additionally, you need to update your input code to cast the inputs to integers, rather than keeping them as strings.

Comment: is there a way to keep the equations in? like a different coding method? also i thought i did convert the inputs.... h = input ("......") , int(h)        is that not correct??

Comment: I'm going to explain how you need to fix your updated code in my main answer (at the bottom)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, if you are accepting my answer, please accept the answer formally (checkmark under up/down votes)